# list available java packages and classes within clojure

Tags: java, reflection, clojure, leiningen

In clojure, the answers to [How to list the functions of a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace) are useful if I have a namespace in mind, in particular `(ns-imports 'my-package)` can tell me about Java code that has been imported.  I can find the list of namespaces with `(all-ns)`. Is there a similar way to find the list of all available java packages, and to preview the java classes that have not been imported yet?

I'm making a lot of JARs and .class files available from Leiningen via `:resource-paths` and `:java-source-paths` respectively.  But since I'm new to the Java codebase, I don't actually know off the top of my head what packages are defined in order to import them.  I could do something with find, xargs, and grep, but it would be nice to have this information available programmatically.  Furthermore, in the future, I would like to be able to do "reflection" over the Java codebase from within Clojure, for instance, noticing when a new class has been defined.

In the LISP world, there is a function called `do-external-symbols' and I googled for that, turning up [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/rqWbiFulju8) discussion from 2007.  It seems things have been solved for Clojure itself, but it's less clear about Clojure's view of Java.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cider/emacs or even just `lein repl`, there's good auto-complete functionality accessible by the tab-button.

```
=> (java.lang.B  <press tab>
java.lang.Boolean  java.lang.BootstrapMethodError  java.lang.Byte
```

This functionality seems to be driven by the library [compliment](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/compliment), by Alexander Yakushev, so I suggest you take a close look on how it works!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember you can call Java code from Clojure. I recently discovered a Library called "Reflections" from Google that will list anything in your classpath for you. I have analysed classes that were JPA entities with this library, it was quite easy to use.

Comment: Here are things that can make this answer way better: a link to that library and an example of code that actually lists classes. Or at least a link to the docs that has or references one.