# Can you list the contents of a namespace or module in F#

Tags: f#

Similar to [this question about clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace), is it possible to list the contents of a namespace or module in F#? When I open a namespace for a loaded DLL I'm not receiving an error that the namespace doesn't exist, but then when I try to use the documented functions I'm seeing errors that the namespace doesn't exist.

I'm looking for a programatic way of listing values and methods and not relying on the IDE. For example if I loaded up the F# repl I'm looking for something similar to:

```
> #r "mylib.DLL"
> open MyLib.Math
> list-namespace-content MyLib.Math;;
   val it : string = """
      MyLib.Math.Add : int -> int -> int
      MyLib.Math.TryDivide : int -> int -> int option
      MyLib.Math.Pi : float
   """
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the errors? (In F#, you can see all functions in a module e.g. `List` when you type `List.` in your editor with F# bindings - though you can list them from code too using Reflection)

Comment: My editor does not have F# bindings. I'm looking for the case of loading a dll in the repl. If you load a source file via `#load` you'll see a printout of namespace/module contents. But if you reference a dll or just open a namespace you won't see the contents.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what editor are you using? There is an F# support for lots of them including Emacs, vim, Atom, Sublime, Xamarin Studio (and obviously VS).

Comment: I use vim but I haven't found anything that is OS/language agnostic for handing tags. I use lots of different systems but carry my vim config with me so I can't be sure I'll have anything besides vim on a workstation.

Comment: I'm not a vim expert, but there is a package for it: https://github.com/fsharp/vim-fsharp (but I'm pretty sure you'll need at least mono and one executable to get decent F# experience in vim).

Comment: I have that plugin installed. It does syntax highlighting but doesn't have the ability to pull contents of a loaded DLL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no such function that does exactly that (I had a glance at the [FSharpReflectionExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469232.aspx) module), but you can write one yourself. All the building blocks are there.

As strange as it may seem, namespaces aren't part of the .NET platform that both F#, C#, and Visual Basic .NET use. At the IL level, types are simply [identified by name, culture, assembly, etc.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) Namespaces simply appear as the first part of the string that makes up a type's name.

However, given an assembly, you can list all its types, or all its public types. Here's an example of the latter, given an F# assembly I recently wrote doing the Tennis kata:

```
> open System.Reflection;;
> let a = Assembly.LoadFrom @"<path>\Ploeh.Katas.Tennis.PropertyBased.dll";;

val a : Assembly =
  Ploeh.Katas.Tennis.PropertyBased, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> let ts = a.GetExportedTypes();;

val ts : System.Type [] =
  [|Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.TennisProperties;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis; Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Player;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Player+Tags;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Point;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Point+Tags;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+PointsData;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+FortyData;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Score;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Score+Tags;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Score+Points;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Score+Forty;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Score+Advantage;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Score+Game|]
```

By looking at the strings to the left of the last `.`, you can find the namespace(s) in use - in this case `Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased`.

However, you should be aware that namespaces can *span multiple assemblies*. As an example, [`System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is defined in `mscorlib`, while [`System.Collections.Generic.Stack<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) is defined in `System`. Thus, using Reflection as above will only give you the members defined in a namespace *in that particular assembly*.

As far as I know, F# modules are compiled to static classes with the `[<CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)>]` attribute. This means that you can list the modules like this:

```
> open Microsoft.FSharp.Core;;
> let modules =
    ts
    |> Array.filter
        (fun t -> t.GetCustomAttributes<CompilationMappingAttribute>()
                    |> Seq.exists (fun attr -> attr.SourceConstructFlags = SourceConstructFlags.Module));;

val modules : System.Type [] =
  [|Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.TennisProperties;
    Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis|]
```

If you want to list all the functions in the `Tennis` module, you can do that like this:

```
> let tm = modules |> Array.find (fun t -> t.Name = "Tennis");;

val tm : System.Type = Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis

> let functions = tm.GetMethods ();;

val functions : MethodInfo [] =
  [|Player other(Player);
    Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Point] incrementPoint(Point);
    Point pointFor(Player, PointsData);
    PointsData pointTo(Player, Point, PointsData);
    Score scorePoints(Player, PointsData); Score scoreForty(Player, FortyData);
    Score scoreDeuce(Player); Score scoreAdvantage(Player, Player);
    Score scoreGame(Player); Score score(Score, Player); Score get_newGame();
    Score scoreSeq(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Ploeh.Katas.PropertyBased.Tennis+Player]);
    System.String pointToString(Point);
    System.String scoreToString(System.String, System.String, Score);
    System.String ToString(); Boolean Equals(System.Object);
    Int32 GetHashCode(); System.Type GetType()|]
```

You may want to filter out some of the inherited methods, like `ToString` and `GetHashCode`.