# How do you know what has been loaded in a clojure REPL environment?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

If I have a running REPL, can I print out all symbols that have been defined?  Is there some way to know what has been defined in the REPL I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the [`dir`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/repl.clj#L188) macro, to list a namespace:

```
user=> (dir user)
nil
user=> (def x :a)
#'user/x
user=> (dir user)
x
nil
user=> (dir clojure.core)
*
*'
*1
*2
*3
*agent*...
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to know what symbols have been defined in a namespace in your REPL use the following code:

```
    (keys (ns-publics 'my-name-space))
```

This answser comes from this Stackoverflow post.
[How to list the functions of a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace)

Use the code below to print to a string.

```
    (pr-str (keys (ns-publics 'my-name-space)))
```

Below is a full example in the form of a screenshot taken of LightTable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find all namespaces:

```
(all-ns)
```

Then, you must decide what you want to collect. For example, the [documentation on namespaces](http://clojure.org/namespaces) lists the following functions for examining namespaces:

- [ns-name](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-name)
- [ns-aliases](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-aliases)
- [ns-imports](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-imports)
- [ns-interns](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-interns)
- [ns-map](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-map)
- [ns-publics](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-publics)
- [ns-refers](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns-refers)

For example, you can have all intern mappings like this:

```
(reduce conj (map ns-interns (all-ns)))
```

Comment: I'd like to add this to be correct too...great answer too.