# clojure: how to list all names reachable in current namespace?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

[According to docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/dir) `dir` lists only "public" vars.
Indeed, it does not show itself, and may not be available in current namespace:

```
user=> (dir user)
nil
user=> 
user=> 
user=> (in-ns 'foo)
#<Namespace foo>
foo=> 
foo=> 
foo=> (dir foo)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: dir in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:17)
```

What other (non-public) types of names/vars exist? (These are probably Java types?) How to list these non-public names? How are they imported into the namespace (or into some "default case" namespaces) on the startup? How default namespaces are searched through in runtime?

For instance in Python: `dir()` lists everything in current namespace, if a referenced variable is not found it is checked among `dir(__builtins__)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list the functions of a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace)

Answer (score 8):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace). You could list all public vars in a namespace using:

```
(keys (ns-publics 'foo))
```

There also is a [dir](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/dir) function like python does, so you could do:

```
 (clojure.repl/dir foo)
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to see the privates as well, you could do:

```
(defn ns-all-vars[n]
   (filter (fn[[_ v]]
             (and (instance? clojure.lang.Var v)
                  (= n (.getName (.ns v)))))
      (ns-map n)))
```

and then simply call

```
(println (map first (ns-all-vars 'foo)))
```

To print all symbols in 'foo namespace.