# How to get all the new symbols in a Clojure namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces

If I have a namespace symbol e.g. `'clojure.core` or a path to a clojure source file how can I get all symbols that are new to the namespace, i.e. not `:refer`-ed or interned in another namespace?

Those symbols would come from top level `def`s (and `defn`s) but also inside `let` bindings and such. My goal is to analyze a namespace and walk the tree effectively doing a find-replace on certain symbols based on a predicate.

Edit: I'm not just looking for top level vars, I'm looking for any symbol. If there's a function with a let binding in it I'm looking for symbol that was bound.

Comment: You will probably want to use clojure.tools.analyzer rather than walking the tree yourself. It should be able to tell you where symbols come from as part of the tree walk anyway, so you won't need this preliminary step of gathering "new" symbols anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list the functions of a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19664649/1455243 .  Your question not exactly the same as [how to list functions of a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747294/how-to-list-the-functions-of-a-namespace/19664649#19664649) but `dir` in that answer does what you want, it appears.

Comment: Not quite, dir won't get me the non-interned symbols in var scope like those in a let binding

Answer (score 3):

The comments you've received tell you how to get the top-level refs, however there's only one way to get the local let bindings, and that's to access the `&env` special form which is only available inside a macro:

```
(defmacro info []
  (println &env))

(def a 5)
(let [b a] (let [c 8] (info)))

;{ b #object[clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding 0x72458346 clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding@72458346],
;  c #object[clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding 0x5f437195 clojure.lang.Compiler$LocalBinding@5f437195]}
```

To get a map of local names to local values, for example:

```
(defmacro inspect []
  (->> (keys &env)
       (map (fn [k] [`'~k k]))
       (into {})))

(let [b a] (let [c 8] (inspect)))
; => {b 5, c 8}
```